# name not defined in "def:" in python

Tags: python, nltk

This script alwayays gives "name 'stop_condition' is not defined" error. What causes this I and how can I solve it?

```
def decode_response(test_input):
 ...
    target_seq[0, 0, target_features_dict['<START>']] = 1.
    
    #A variable to store our response word by word
    decoded_sentence = ''
    
    stop_condition = False

while not stop_condition:
      #Predicting output tokens with probabilities and states
      output_tokens, hidden_state, cell_state = decoder_model.predict([target_seq] + states_value)
#Choosing the one with highest probability
      sampled_token_index = np.argmax(output_tokens[0, -1, :])
      sampled_token = reverse_target_features_dict[sampled_token_index]
      decoded_sentence += " " + sampled_token
...
return decoded_sentence
```

Comment: If your code is indented like in your question, the  `while` loop is not part of the function, so it can't know about `stop_condition`. You probably want to indent the whole part up to `return`.

Comment: If the indentation of your code on your own computer is different than what we see here, please [edit] your question to fix it.

Comment: be careful your loop is not going to stop you never change the value of stop_condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of Indentation While loop is not inside function it is outside of it so stop_condition is defined locally inside function  .
Is this what you are looking for .

```
def decode_response(test_input):
...
    target_seq[0, 0, target_features_dict['<START>']] = 1.

# A variable to store our response word by word
    decoded_sentence = ''

    stop_condition = False


    while not stop_condition:
    # Predicting output tokens with probabilities and states
        output_tokens, hidden_state, cell_state = decoder_model.predict([target_seq] + states_value)
    # Choosing the one with highest probability
        sampled_token_index = np.argmax(output_tokens[0, -1, :])
        sampled_token = reverse_target_features_dict[sampled_token_index]
        decoded_sentence += " " + sampled_token
...
    return decoded_sentence
```